# Using replace with some kind of loop?

Tags: replace, vbscript

I have a variable with the following values:

```
Variable1 = "Apple, Banana, Pineaple, Grape, Coconut"
```

I would like to use the `Replace` to get the following result:

```
VariableX = "<span class="text1">Apple</span> <span class="text2">Banana</span> <span class="text1">Pineapple</span> <span class="text2">Grape</span> <span class="text1">Coconut</span>"
```

So, the first value gets `text1`, the second gets `text2`, the third gets `text1`, the forth gets `text2` and so on, until the end.

Comment: What do you mean by "gets `text1`, the second gets `text2`..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
' Split into an array...
a = Split(Variable1, ",")

' Add each element to a <span> tag...
For i = 0 To UBound(a)
    VariableX = VariableX & "<span class=""text" & i + 1 & """>" & Trim(a(i)) & "</span>"
Next
```

---

**Update with respect to comments:**

To alternate between two values you can put them in an array and use `Mod` to alternatively select one of the values.

```
a = Split(Variable1, ",")
strClasses = Array("text-info", "text-warning")

' Add each element to a <span> tag...
For i = 0 To UBound(a)
    VariableX = VariableX & "<span class=""" & strClasses(i Mod 2) & """>" & Trim(a(i)) & "</span>"
Next
```

Comment: Thanks. The result is generating text1, text2, text3, text4... I am looking for just 2 strings. In my example was text1 and text2, but the real case is text-info and text-warning. Thanks again.

Comment: How are you associating `text-info` and `text-warning` with your array elements? Are you just alternating `text-info` and `text-warning`?

Comment: Yeah, just alternating. The first is `text-info`, the second `text-warning`, and loop until the end. Thanks.